# Xcode 11 and Light/Dark Colors

Tags: ios

After updating to Xcode 11 and Swift 5 for iOS 13 compatibility the dark-mode was introduced.

When I open my Storyboard I had a set of Colors ("custom Colors") defined and to be able to adapt them into dark mode I created a Color Asset. Where the light version is the current "custom color" and the dark one a darker version of it. 
But when I use the Color Asset the color is different even if the HEX and RGB Code are completely different. 
Am I missing something?

Here the Colors : 
[image]

Where Custom is defined as (43,133,211) which is equal to #2B85D3
And "WizyCyan" is defined as (43,133,211) which is again equal to #2B85D3

Thanks in advance.